# C++ parsing small float from string

Tags: c++, parsing

I want my code to read parameters in from a file. I have this line in that file:

```
tol=1e-10
```

and I use `atof` to parse this into a float:

```
double tol;
char * c = "1e-10"
tol=atof(c);
```

However, it is parsed as `0` instead of `1e-10`.

**Edit**: It turns out that it does parse correctly, I'm sorry to have bothered you guys. I forgot that `printf` doesn't show small values by default. I suspected this at the first place since one of my checks froze.

Comment: How do you print it out, how do you know that it's parsed as 0?

Comment: Your sample will give the right value tol = 1e-010. Did you check in your application?

Comment: -1 for not checking your sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double d = atof( "1e-10" );
    cout << d << endl;
}
```

prints 1e-10.

Comment: And what will `d` be for `atof("blah")`?

Comment: @sbi That's not what the question asked. Of course, in the real world one would never use atof - I was pointing out that the code he posted did in fact work.

Comment: But you haven't said so, and now you have "educated" one more newbie to use the wrong function, and he will certainly use it in the real world. (That's why I always insist on providing example code that's right in all aspects, even seemingly irrelevant code.)

Answer (score 2):

How are you printing the result, make sure you have lots of numbers after the point. It may be a rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `std::atof()` returns `0` in case of an error, so you can't tell the two apart.

Since this is a C++ question, why don't you use streams? Something like this:

```
double get_tol(std::istream& is)
{
  std::string key;
  if( !is>>key || key!="tol" ) throw "You need error handling here!";
  char equal;
  if( !is>>equal || equal!='=' ) throw "You need error handling here!";
  double d;
  if( !is>>d )throw "You need error handling here!";
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `c` into a `std::string` and use a `stringstream` instead.